# Bundler is not self-aware: claims to have version 0.0.1, but is really 1.0.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, osx-lion

EDIT:

I'm an idiot -- I figured out the problem. In a gem I had written a while back, I had `VERSION='0.0.1'`, and for some reason that overrode the version number of bundler.

Won't do that again...

---

Some background information: on an OS X Lion computer I'm using RVM with Macruby on a Rails 3.0.7 project. I set Macruby and my current gemset to be the default. When I try to run bundle install, I get the following message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 1.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (0.0.1)

Your version of Bundler is older than the one requested by the Gemfile.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

When I run `gem list bundle`, it shows exactly one installation at version 1.0.18. I suspect that somehow the RVM default setting is not applied all the way through the system. But the system ruby does not have any bundler installed, much less this elusive 0.0.1.

Anybody know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be possible that your `bundle` executable is still pointing to an old version of the gem?

Comment: Quite possibly, but this is a completely new computer, with a fresh install of RVM and rails. So I don't think any other version of bundler has ever been on the machine. Right now I'm reinstalling RVM, and going to build LLVM before installing Macruby. I think that may have had something to do with it. I'll report back if that fixes it...

Comment: Okay, reinstalling RVM fresh and after building LLVM didn't work. Do you know how I could track down why it isn't using the gemset specified by RVM?